# Can top of brick wall be level?

Tags: walls, drainage, brick, masonry

I understand it is preferable that brick wall tops be sloped so that water drains off instead of permeating into the wall causing accelerated decay. One of the reasons I would like to leave it flat as is is because I rest ladder feet on it to service a wall on the other side of these stairs.

Can the top of a brick wall be flat or somehow treated with something so it resists the elements?

[image]

Comment: Bazillions of brick walls the world over are level on top. Even with a slope it'll get wet. Make a choice and deal with the consequences.

Comment: Cap it with something waterproof, or make a low slope that the ladder can handle. Most paved patios are sloped like 1:50 .

Comment: There are two good answers. If you have a winter you should follow one of them so that sitting water doesn't penetrate small cracks, freeze and start a vicious cycle of destroying your wall.

Comment: Even if you're sloped at 2%, the ladder would be fine.  The ladder would be supported by the fence anyway.

Answer (score 5):

**Coping stones.**

They can be any profile, flat, sloped, ridge-cap… They prevent water ingress between the brick courses and also between brick and render. Water ingress plus frost equals broken mortar, bricks, render popping off. At simplest they're just a flat piece of concrete, like half a paving flag [which often they are].
You don't really need to slope them for them to fulfil their purpose, but you could tilt them just a degree or two if you want them to drain a specific way.

Here's just a random sample of the first few a search engine threw up

[image]

Comment: Careful you don't step in the search engine throw up! (That's "sick" to those on your side of the Pond. Provides humor to the more immature of us on this side. :D )

Comment: @FreeMan - same this side of the pond, in the right context. I presume the colloquial use in this way is related.

Answer (score 2):

All you need for drainage is 1-2% slope (1/8-1/4" per foot) and if you slope it that much towards the wall you want to work on with the ladder, it will make the ladder footing (typically only 3-4" long, so ends of the feet off level by 1/32-11/128")  ever so slightly more secure (if you slope it that much away, ever so slightly less.)

That's considerably less than ordinary variations in ground you might set a ladder on. Or I might anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen 11/128" written anywhere. I would give this a +1 just for that, if the rest hadn't already merited the up click.